# Load data from firebase to a label?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data in firebase that I would like to load into a UILabel with Swift.

My data structure looks like:

```
like-1bf89addclose
 artists
 -LP6zVO8iekRMMOWe7nm
 artistGenre: pop
 artistName: postmalone
 id: 920930
```

And my swift code looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    refHandle = ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        print(dataDict)

    })

    ref.child("artists").observeSingleEventOfType(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        let artist = snapshot.value!["artistName"] as! String
        let genre = snapshot.value!["artistGenre"] as! String

        self.artistlLabel.text = artist
        self.genreLabel.text = genre

    })
}
```

where's my mistake?  I've tried searching online, but most examples only explain how to put input into tableviews, which has a different code I tried to understand and restructure but couldn't.  I know there has to be something wrong with my ref but I can't figure it out.

I'm following a youtube tutorial and this works:

```
let userID: String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
ref.child("Users").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let email = snapshot.value!["Email"] as! String
    let password = snapshot.value!["Password"] as! String

    self.emailLabel.text = email
    self.passwordLabel.text = password

})
```

**issue with this code is I don't need that authentication part (no users have to log in on my app, they're just inputing info in).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `-LP6zVO8iekRMMOWe7nm` level in your reference. Try this:

```
ref.child("artists/-LP6zVO8iekRMMOWe7nm").observeSingleEventOfType(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let artist = snapshot.value!["artistName"] as! String
    let genre = snapshot.value!["artistGenre"] as! String
    print("\(artist) \(genre)")

    self.artistlLabel.text = artist
    self.genreLabel.text = genre
})
```

If you want to load all artists, you can load `/artists` and then loop over the results:

```
ref.child("artists/-LP6zVO8iekRMMOWe7nm").observeSingleEventOfType(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
  for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    let artist = child.value!["artistName"] as! String
    let genre = child.value!["artistGenre"] as! String
    print("\(artist) \(genre)")
  }
})
```